# Is it possible to sum output JSON array elements and store it in an array?

Tags: php, json

I have a php script that returns me a JSON string of varchar(50) elements. I would like to sum all those numbers together and store them in a variable. Is it possible?
Maybe loop trough it...

This is the output of my JSON string:

```
`12345678910111213141516`
```

PHP code

```
<?php

include_once("./conn.php");

if(isset($_POST["toggle_btn"])){
    if(!empty($_POST["zone_field"])){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM results";
        $res = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo json_decode($row['waarde']);
            }
          } else {
            echo "No rows have been found";
          }

          $conn->close();
    } else {
        echo "Field is empty";
    }
} else {
    echo 'Did not hit the btn';
}
```

?>

Thanks a lot

Comment: That isn't JSON. Is this really the correct data? But yes, whatever format they're really in, it should be possible to extract all the numbers and add them up. What have you tried? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Maybe add the code that arrived at this?

Comment: "i used json_encode()"... That's not possible, sorry. Not unless you did 16 separate calls to json_encode() and the concatenated the results?? But doing that doesn't make a valid JSON object. And it implies that you encoded what were originally just 16 separate numbers, so it would have been easier to just add them together before you encoded them.

Comment: @ADyson i tried to do it with a $sum that starts with 0. I went true all numbers with a foreach loop and store the sum in the $sum variable. But i only obtain errors..

Comment: Unless you show us the code and what the errors are, then clearly we don't have any way of fixing it. But first you should fix the data, and the code which generates it, because it's not in a sensible format. And then you might find it's easier to work on the data once it's valid (because if you make it into valid JSON, you can simply decode it and then use it like any other PHP variable)

Comment: I posted the code above

Comment: I can see you're potentially printing the $sum variable multiple times (once for each row in the results) - how many rows does your query return?.

Comment: Also, why don't you just use a SQL `SUM()` function

Comment: And yes if the query returns multiple rows, then you're running json_encode multiple times too, which makes no sense. And you're only encoding a single value, which probably also makes no sense. It would really help if you showed us the source data in the table, or at least a sample of a few rows.

Comment: "numbers are stored as varchar(50)" ... Well fix that then. Why would you store numbers in a string field??

Comment: @ADyson I changed my numbers to floats in my database. I also changed the code above. Now i obtain `12345678910111213141516` (1-16) as output. Is it possible to count them together now?

Comment: Sure. But don't use PHP to do that. `SELECT SUM(waarde) AS total FROM results`.

Comment: Perfect, and how can i echo it out?

Comment: Very similar to how you echo it now. You know there'll be just one row, that's the only difference, so you don't need the loop. `$res = $conn->query($sql); if ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) { echo $row["total"]; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this much more easily with a SQL query using `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(waarde) AS total FROM results
```

And this will simplify the PHP too:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(waarde) AS total FROM results";
$res = $conn->query($sql);

if ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo $row["total"]; 
}
```

P.S. Since you're just outputting a single number, there's no need for JSON (valid or otherwise) anywhere in this task at all.